# Simple spacing CSS

Tags: css

I have designed a navbar for my website; you can see it at http://jsfiddle.net/ToddStyles/D2tZH/.

[image: Screenshot]

What CSS I would use to change the spacing between them? I used an unordered list to make it and changed the `display` to `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are displaying elements inline, HTML will parse any whitespace as a spacebar character. So, you can either comment out the space between list items, i.e.:

```
<li>...</li><!--
--><li>...</li>
```

Or, display them as block level elements and float them:

```
ul {
    overflow: hidden; /* To prevent collapse */
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

---

With regards to the Fiddle you have posted, you have used the `<img>` tag incorrectly. It is self-closing, and it should not be used to nest anything.

p/s: And please, don't use link shortener just because SO prevents you from posting a Fiddle link due to a lack of code. The rule is there for a reason — providing us code gives your question **context**.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re looking to increase the width, you can apply a left margin to consecutive `<li>`s easily:

```css
#navbar li + li {
    margin-left: 0.2em;
}
```

[Here’s your fiddle back.](http://jsfiddle.net/rninty/D2tZH/3/) I fixed it to use `inline-block` to make the layout break less when it inevitably wraps on a smaller screen. And do take into account that we can’t see images on your computer across the internet.